# How to execute program in chrooted PHP-FPM?

Tags: php, linux, shell, nginx

I am now writing a small script to execute `gpg` from `PHP (FPM)` but somehow PHP does not allow me to execute any binary/shell script and return exit code **127**. But  if I execute those in php-cli it works just fine.

PHP Configuration:

PHP: `php-fpm`

Webserver: `nginx`

chroot `/user/home/php-root`

chdir `/`

Safemode `Off`

Disable `exec*`?: No

I tried the ff:

1. I have tried execute `exec('whoami')` or `ls` all return NULL and gives exitcode 127
2. `shell_exec()` all commands return NULL
3. `system()` also return NULL
4. Use full path
5. Use `2>&1` return NULL
6. Copy `gpg`, `whoami` in `chrooted-root/bin`
7. Execute binary from `chrooted-root/bin`

As far as I tried, *nothing* works.

Are there anyone able to make PHP-FPM execute shell/binary in chrooted environment?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

I found that copying `/bin/sh` to `chrooted-root/bin` worked. Also needed dependencies:

```
$ ldd /bin/sh
    linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffc098c6000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f2e92d52000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f2e9331e000)
```

So I had to copy `/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6` and `/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2` under my chrooted directory.

I'm not sure if it's `/bin/sh` under all distros, might be `/bin/bash` or something.